# Delete selected rows in uitable

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

Is there a way to delete a row in `uitable` using the mouse right click, similar to the way done in excel? I am looking to do so in order to save just the data I want and not all the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a `pushbutton`:

```
function myTable 

close all
h = figure('Position',[600 400 402 100],'numbertitle','off','MenuBar','none');

defaultData = rand(5,2);
uitable(h,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1],...
              'Data', defaultData,... 
              'Tag','myTable',...
              'ColumnName', [],'RowName',[],...
              'CellSelectionCallback',@cellSelect);

tb = uitoolbar(h);
uipushtool(tb,'ClickedCallback',@deleteRow);
end

function cellSelect(src,evt)
index = evt.Indices;
if any(index)
    rows = index(:,1);
    set(src,'UserData',rows);
end
end

function deleteRow(~,~)
th = findobj('Tag','myTable');
data = get(th,'Data');
rows = get(th,'UserData');
mask = (1:size(data,1))';
mask(rows) = [];
data = data(mask,:);
set(th,'Data',data);
end
```

for example:

[image]

Select a row and push the button to delete it.
You can also select **multiple rows and delete them at once!**

It's not exactly what you wanted, but your request seems quite hard to realize. You will need to deal with java objects, which is not the most trivial way to go.

I don't want to say it's impossible, but you'll save a lot of time if you just go with the `pushbutton`. Matlab is just not made for that :)

In this example the button has no icon, to add one, read [this article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/figure-toolbar-components)